# VBA Excel - Modify data on cells through VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I've written some VBA code to the following:

1. Let's say that I have an spreadsheet with this columns

[Cost1] [Cost2] [Cost3] [TotalCost] [Margin%] [Margin$] [Price]

1. If the user modifies the costs, the total cost changes and the Margin$ and Price because they depend on the cost and the Margin%
2. If the user modifies the Price, the cost don't change but the Margin% and the Margin$ do change, because they depend on the new price.

I was not able to add protected formulas to the Price column because the user may want to change that value, thus the formula would be erased. So I decided to code VBA which works perfectly calculation wise. However, I've lost some of the most valued features of excel: e.g. If a want to copy the value of one price to several other rows, it just triggers the recalculation for the firs row where it is copied but not for the others. I'v also lost the ability of UNDO after exiting the cell.

To detect that a cell was modified I'm using the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If (Target.Column = Range("Price").Column)                 
    Call calcMargins(Target.Row)
  End If

  If (Target.Column = Range("Cost1").Column) or _
  If (Target.Column = Range("Cost2").Column) or _
  If (Target.Column = Range("Cost3").Column) or
    Call calcMargins(Target.Row)
    Call calcPrice(Target.Row)
  End If
```

Comment: Have you considered using the formulas and using VBA (double click / button,/ etc) to reestablish the formula in case a user wants to?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

I have deliberately broken down the code into several If statements and duplicate codes for understanding perspective. For example

```
        Cells(Target.Row, 4) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ TotalCost Changes
        Cells(Target.Row, 6) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ Margin$ Changes
        Cells(Target.Row, 7) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ Price Changes
```

Please put them in a common procedure.

Also note the use of `Error Handling` and `Application.EnableEvents`. These two are a **MUST** when working with `Worksheet_Change`. `Application.EnableEvents = False` ensures that the code doesn't get into a *possible* infinite loop in case there are recursive actions. `Error Handling` not only handles the error but also stops the code from breaking up by showing you an error message and then resetting the `Application.EnableEvents` to `True` and finally exiting the code gracefully.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then        '<~~ When Cost 1 Changes
        Cells(Target.Row, 4) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ TotalCost Changes
        Cells(Target.Row, 6) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ Margin$ Changes
        Cells(Target.Row, 7) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ Price Changes

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then    '<~~ When Cost 2 Changes
        Cells(Target.Row, 4) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ TotalCost Changes
        Cells(Target.Row, 6) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ Margin$ Changes
        Cells(Target.Row, 7) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ Price Changes

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then    '<~~ When Cost 3 Changes
        Cells(Target.Row, 4) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ TotalCost Changes
        Cells(Target.Row, 6) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ Margin$ Changes
        Cells(Target.Row, 7) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ Price Changes

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(7)) Is Nothing Then    '<~~ When Cost Price Changes
        Cells(Target.Row, 5) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ Margin% Changes
        Cells(Target.Row, 6) = "Some Calculation"               '<~~ Margin$ Changes
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

I am assuming that Row 1 is protected and the user is not gonna change that. If the Header row is unprotected then you will have check for the row number withing the `If` Statements to exclude Row 1

**FOLLOWUP**

> > > I select one of the costs (first of Cost1), do a Ctrl+C, select all cells under Cost 3 and do Crl+V, it copies the values but it only re-calculates the TotalCost for the firs cell of the selection. Than you for your help!!! – Ronald Valdivia 24 mins ago

Ah I see what you are trying :)

Use this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cl As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cl In Target
            Cells(cl.Row, 4) = Cells(cl.Row, 1) + Cells(cl.Row, 2) + Cells(cl.Row, 3)
        Next
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cl In Target
            Cells(cl.Row, 4) = Cells(cl.Row, 1) + Cells(cl.Row, 2) + Cells(cl.Row, 3)
        Next
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cl In Target
            Cells(cl.Row, 4) = Cells(cl.Row, 1) + Cells(cl.Row, 2) + Cells(cl.Row, 3)
        Next
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. I just tested the code but still the same results: 1) Undo does not work, 2) When copying value to more than one cell only the event only trigger for the first cell.

Comment: 1) Undo will not work. That is by default when you run the vba code 2) I tested the code before posting so I would recommend if you can upload a sample file in say www.wikisend.com and share the link here so that i can have a look at it.

Comment: 1) Is there a way to mimic the undo? 2) I posted my sample code in http://wikisend.com/download/563698/TestVBA.xlsm.   Thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: We will come to undo later. Ok I checked the file, it is working as expected (after I deleted the last line "protect")

Comment: Sorry to bother you. Can you please post the code updated because it is not working for me. I select one of the costs (first of Cost1), do a Ctrl+C, select all cells under Cost 3 and do Crl+V, it copies the values but it only re-calculates the TotalCost for the firs cell of the selection. Than you for your help!!!

Comment: If helps, I just posted a screen cap of how it works http://wikisend.com/download/203672/TestVBA.avi

Comment: See the followup in the above post :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I works!!! now I have to figure out the "undo" think. Thank you very very much.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with undo?

Comment: You mentioned the undo won't work by default when I run the vba code. I'd like to know if there is a way to make it work. Perhaps coding some VBA code and adding a button to execute it. Thank you.

Comment: It's very complicated :) See this link. http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/UndoWithVBA00.asp

Comment: You are the best!!! Thanks a lot!! I really appreciate all the time and effort you have invested to help me out. I owe you big time. Thanks a lot!!! –

Comment: @RonaldValdivia: glad Siddharth Rout helped you. Yet, if this answer fits you, please accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234 for more information